# How to open a div with slideUp in jquery with scroll bar down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My title may not understand to all. Here is my question:

I have sticky footer strip bottom of the page with a button beside to it. when I click the button, I need to show a mega footer with sliding. I'm successful till here. but my question is when I show mega footer, the scroll bar stays at the same location. I wanted the scroll bar to stick bottom (focus on footer strip.)

HTML code:

```
<div class="body-container">
    <div class="my-content"> <span> Body Wrapper</span></div>
    <div class="footer-strip">Mini-footer-strip </div>
    <button id="show2">Click here</button>
    <div id="two">    
       Mega Footer Menu
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#show2').click(function() {
        $('#two').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.body-container{width:90%; display:block;height:auto;position:absolute;}
.my-content{
    height:600px;
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    background-color:#ecdeca;}

div {
    background-color: #fff9d7;  
    border: 1px solid #e2c822;  
    color: #333333;  
    font-size: 13px;  
    font-weight: bold;  
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
} 
#two {
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
}
#show2{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:9999;
}

.footer-strip{
    height:20px;
    display:block; 
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#eacdea;
    width:70%;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Hope my question is clear. :D

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/srikanth_naalla/j23vc3kh/1/)

Comment: Right off the hip i would say, use scrollTop() method of jQuery to scroll window during and after the toggle, or make bigger footer strip absolute, but then you need more code to position it.

Comment: check this.. http://jsfiddle.net/srikanth_naalla/j23vc3kh/

Comment: I don't think there is no normal way to do such a thing. There is quite weird workaround - you can see it in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrobvpw6/2/).

Comment: But if you want to scroll to bottom only when `.slideToggle()` is done, then you can simply use something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrobvpw6/3/).

Comment: but the slider is jumping from existing position to the bottom, :/

Comment: @srikanth_naalla yes, it is. I doubt there is any other ways to scroll down on `.slideToggle()`.

Comment: @Regent will that be possible with .slideUp() and slideDown();

Comment: @srikanth_naalla nope, it will be just the same. The only thing I can suggest is to reduce `setTimeout` delay for very small value (1-5 milliseconds). It will look smoother: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/xrobvpw6/4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#show2').click(function() {
        $('#two').slideToggle();

        $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#two").offset().top + $('window').height()
    }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Add animate scroll for the div.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuxgw1mn/)

As you asked another scroll bar to down:

[Scrollbar down fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuxgw1mn/1/)

```
#two {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    scroll:overflow;
}
```

Comment: cant we fix the scroll bar to down? while animating the mega footer?

Comment: `$('html, body')` can be simplified into `$('body')`. And I do not think `$("#two").offset().top + $('window').height()` will give desired result, especially when `#two` has more height than `window` has.

Comment: @divakar: Thanks divakar, fiddle solved 80%, but I want to fix scroll bar to down, instead of animating.

Comment: yes, only while sliding up the big footer. the scroll bar position should be same as when big footer is closing.

Comment: @srikanth_naalla understood what you asking. Done the changes. Please check that out.

Comment: sorry, but the big footer is overlapping on body content

Comment: @divakar _please upvote the answer first_ - it's like blackmail, extortion. Never write such things again.

Comment: @Regent Thanks for the information. I will not repeat it :)

Comment: any luck to my question?

Comment: What you mean by overlapping. Can you explain more?

Comment: my fiddle explains it all. the big footer should not be placed on the body wrapper. your recent fiddle is placed the big footer on body wrapper.